# php session_start: failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I have a problem with session, i have change repertory with php like this

```
session_save_path('/w/w/session');
session_start();
```

The message error:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/w/w/session/sess_bace6057bf24184f0c1c26c002bf9141, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /w/w/config.php on line 3
```

I have add chmod 777 in filezila but not work

I have tested with .htaccess i have error 500

I dont have access to php.ini in my host.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: did you change the permissions for the entire path? for each folder in the /w/w/session path

Comment: i dont have access to this repertory /w/w is /home/website.com/ in my root i have 3 folder (www, session, tmp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path in `session_save_path('/w/w/session');` is not the one you need.

Try one of those:

```
session_save_path('./session');
session_save_path('/session');
session_save_path('/tmp');
```

On a shared host, you are not as flexible as on a rootserver, and your `/www` is chrooted, that means, the real path, which you cannot access then is something like `/var/www/user3183123/www`.